# Regex to allow numbers containing dash

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using the following handler to allow only numbers as an input.

```
$(document).on("input", "[data-rule-number=true]", function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

I would like to modify it to be able to contain a dash ex. "200-300" (max one dash so not "200-300-400") but can't wrap my head around the needed regex. Maybe I shouldn't use replace in the first place but I like this solution as it is based on "input" event and works for all devices.

So the valid input should be either number (ex. "200") or number dash number (ex. "200-300").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression should allow a dash in the input string:

```
value.replace(/^([^-]+-)|-+/g, '$1').replace(/[^\d-]+/g, '')
```